# Remove specific xmlns from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<Orders xmlns="hi/hi" xmlns:shipping="hello/hi" xmlns:message="hello/hi" message:timestamp="2018-04-23T14:28:39Z">
    <orderLineStatusUpdate orderNumber="CCORD002" line="0">
        <orderLineStatus>inPicking</orderLineStatus>
        <shipmentNumber>1</shipmentNumber>
        <leadTime unit="days">
            <shipping:min>1</shipping:min>
            <shipping:max>1</shipping:max>
        </leadTime>
    </orderLineStatusUpdate>
</Orders>
```

Expected output:

```
<Orders message:timestamp="2018-04-23T14:28:39Z">
    <orderLineStatusUpdate orderNumber="CCORD002" line="0">
        <orderLineStatus>inPicking</orderLineStatus>
        <shipmentNumber>1</shipmentNumber>
        <leadTime unit="days">
            <shipping:min>1</shipping:min>
            <shipping:max>1</shipping:max>
        </leadTime>
    </orderLineStatusUpdate>
</Orders>
```

This is the XSLT that I am using. It will remove `shipping:min` and `shipping:max` from the code. I just want to remove `xmlns`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
       </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*[local-name(.)='message']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but my XSLT code is removing `shipping:min` and `shipping:max` also

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the XSLT you are having trouble with? Thank you!

Comment: @TimC i updated

Comment: @TimC PLease help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Your expected output is invalid XML, because it contains an undeclared namespace prefix `shipping:`. The more important question here is *why* you want to remove nodes that are correct to express the XML structure you have.

I suggest you read up on [XML namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx) to better understand what you're actually doing here, and why it doesn't make sense.

Comment: if i want to concetenate 'shipping' with min and max then how i an achieve this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289781/concate-the-text-shipping-using-xslt-1-0

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `match="*"` template rule by two template rules, one to match elements whose namespace is to be stripped, the other to match elements whose namespace is to be retained:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You will want different match patterns on the two rules, perhaps

```
match="*[namespace-uri()='hi/hi']"
```

and

```
match="*[namespace-uri()='hello/hi']"
```

but you could omit the predicate one of them to make it the default.